# How to get my notification to contionuosly alert my user windows 8.1 device or c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8, notifications, push-notification

I have successfully been able to send and receive notifications between my windows 8.1 application and my server using WNS. The only problem is when my toast notification comes through to my device it shows for about 10 seconds then disappears. This is no good for me as if my user was not with their device they would miss the notification completely. So what I want to know is where I fix this problem? 
1.Is there a setting in the device that I can change to have the notification continue for more than 10 seconds. Or to make sure the notification keeps working till the user has touched the notification or device.
2. Or do I need to specify in the server that the same notification needs to be sent every say 10 minutes till the user has client app side has acknowledged that the notification has been seen?
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: A better approach might be to update your live tile with information that notifies your users to do something.

Answer (score 0):

Stuart's answer is correct.  A Toast notification is not meant to be continuously visible, but a Live Tile notification can be.  I think you would be best off by throwing a toast notification to immediately notify the customer and then have a live tile that shows the information as well.

Throwing a notification every 10 minutes is incredibly annoying.  I would delete your app in a heartbeat if you did that to my phone/machine.